# Having problems with aspnetsqlmembershipprovider

Tags: asp.net

I have developed in asp.net for years and usually set up membership and roles in the same sql server database I use for cms. However, because I only need to password protect a couple of admin pages in my current project, I thought I would try the built in Account folder setup that Microsoft includes in its website template. So far it's been a nightmare.

I have the login working on my local machine, but when I uploaded to the server, I get the  following error:

" A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)" The connection string provided by Microsoft says instance = true.

GoDaddy, the hosting provider, responded to my request to see if they could correct the connection string, by saying that the MDF file in the App_Data folder would only work on a dedicated server. (I'm skeptical...)

Making things even more challenging, I can open the sql express (.mdf) database and see the account I set up using the registration form. But when I try to test the default aspnetsqlmembershipprovider with the web configuration page inside my ap, I get a message saying:

Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.

I would really appreciate help in understanding what is happening so, if there isn't a duh solution, I can at least dismantle this thing in an intelligent way and then set up authentication in the webconfig, which would have taken ten minutes.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy is wrong.  Put your connection here and take a look at it for you.  Remember to remove your login id and pwd in the connection string.

Comment: This is the string that Microsoft puts into the page which connects with the database Microsoft puts into the app_Data folder. It does that fine on my localhost server, but not when uploaded:<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> Forgot to mention that there is no password because it is an internal file.

Comment: try remove  Integrated Security=SSPI;   from your connection string.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I can't determine whether it would work because last night I deleted the whole folder and set up credentials in the webconfig file. I will accept your response because it seems reasonable.